# Singleton - I can create multiple instances

Tags: c#, design-patterns, singleton

I thought the point of a singleton was I could only initialize one instance at a time? If this is correct, then I must have a fault in my C# console application code (see below).

Would some one please be kind enough to inform me if my understanding of a singleton is correct or if there is an error in my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace TestSingleton
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Singleton t = Singleton.Instance;
            t.MyProperty = "Hi";

            Singleton t2 = Singleton.Instance;
            t2.MyProperty = "Hello";

            if (t.MyProperty != "")
                Console.WriteLine("No");

            if (t2.MyProperty != "")
                Console.WriteLine("No 2");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public sealed class Singleton
    {
        private static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();

        public string MyProperty { get; set; }

        private Singleton()
        {}

        static Singleton()
        { }

        public static Singleton Instance { get { return instance; } }
    }
}
```

Comment: And there no need to assign the instance to a local variable, with a singleton just use it directly.

Comment: What you feel fault in your code?

Comment: to see what is going on put a breakpoint in your singleton constructor - or a console.writeline, you are only getting one instance

Comment: If you would show the output, it would be helpful to see what happens.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Yes, I should have done, then would have realised it was a reference type!

Comment: @DaleBurrell - The only way I can do this would be to change my call to *Singleton.GetInstance();* and create a new method in my Singleton class like: *public static Singleton GetInstance(){return instance;}* Is this what you meant?

Comment: I think you are misleading yourself as you arent looking at the MyProperty value to confirm to yourself it is the same instance.. I would have understood confusion if you had had code outside the class trying to make a "new Singleton()" ..

Comment: No Dave, you can access a singleton property happily without assigning locally e.g. Singleton.Instance.MyProperty;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Infact you have only **one** instance here. You get 2 pointers

```
Singleton t = Singleton.Instance; //FIRST POINTER
t.MyProperty = "Hi";

Singleton t2 = Singleton.Instance; //SECOND POINTER
t2.MyProperty = "Hello";
```

But they both are pointing to the **same** memory location.

Comment: Ah... Now I understand. Because it's a reference type right!?

Comment: You didn't make 2 sinatnces of the class, but make only one, just point to the **same** instance from 2 different locations.

Comment: @Dave what made you think you have two ones in the first place? Of course neither "Hi" nor "Hello" is == "" ...

Comment: @DaveRook: correct, cause it's a reference type. In general you can avoid all that ctor code, if you declare class simply *static*. You guranteed in this way that **none** can create non static instance of it.

Comment: @Fildor Yes, that was part of the problem. I just assumed that the singleton would have caused a compile error when I tried *Singleton t2 = Singleton.Instace;*! The fact it didn't error made me think it was a new instance.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", t.MyProperty, t2.MyProperty);
```

Just tested your code and it gives `Hello Hello` and not `Hi Hello`. So you were manipulating the same instance

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have only one instance in your sample program. The variables t1 and t2 point to the very same instance of the object.
The object you created is

```
private static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();
```

And both t1 and t2 point to the same object. As said by someone else in memory there is just one object created.

Answer (score 1):

Your **reference** to `Singleton.Instance;` is a reference to `Singleton.instance` and so a reffence to one single object. There is no creation of a second Singleton **object**